# Response cache controlling - setting expiration

Tags: javascript, asp.net, http-headers

I have questions about correct configuration response cache control.
What is the problem ?
When I do action on dev environment sometimes I got error 502 bad gateway. This problem appears for many users during the testing.
But when we clear cache and actually whole history in user  browser everything works fine.
I found in code response cache configuration which looks like:

```
Response.Expires = 0;
```

`Response.ExpiresAbsolute =Add.Hours(-1)`.
And also added headers like `pragma = no-cache` and `cache-control = private`
And another options `Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"`

I understand what every options means but I can not find answer that any options does not exclude another options what couse that cache does not work good and help manually clear options.

Could you give me information that I need this 5 elements of configuration.